# Strange behavior after ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a "subscription module" for a website, everything works fine except
the Ajax part.

When I click the **first** time on "subscribe" the button changes to "unsubscribe", but if i click on "unsubscribe" button again without refreshing the page, the button changes to "subscribe" and than to "unsubscribe" again.

Like if I clicked it twice.

This is what I can see from "chrome -> network tab"

```
engine/ajax/mywatch.php?subscribe_id=3385&action=plus&skin=Default
engine/ajax/mywatch.php?subscribe_id=3385&action=minus&skin=Default
```

html

```
<a id="subscript-id-3385" onclick="doMywatch('3385', 'plus'); return false;" >subscribe</a>
```

javascript

```
<script>
    function doMywatch(a,b){ShowLoading("");$.get(root+"engine/ajax/mywatch.php",{subscribe_id:a,action:b,skin:skin},function(b){HideLoading("");$("#subscript-id-"+a).html(b)});return!1}
</script>
```

php

```
    if( $_GET['action'] == "plus" ) {

    echo <<<HTML
    <script>
            alert('plus ');
    </script>
    HTML;
            $row = $db->super_query("SELECT subscriptions FROM " . PREFIX . "_mywatch WHERE user_id={$member_id['user_id']}" );
            $list = explode(",", $row['subscriptions']);

            foreach ( $list as $daten ) {
                    if( $daten == $id ) $achecker = "stop";
            }


            $error = "";

            if( $achecker != "stop" ){

                    $list[] = $id;
                    $subsc = $db->safesql(implode( ",", $list ));
                    //$subsc = implode( ",", $list );
                    if( $row['subscriptions'] == "" ) $subsc = $id;
                    $db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_mywatch set subscriptions='$subsc' where user_id = '{$member_id['user_id']}'" );
            }
                    $buffer = "<a onclick=\"doMywatch('" . $id . "', 'minus'); \" title=\"" . $lang['news_minfav'] . "\">unsubscribe</a>";

} elseif( $_GET['action'] == "minus" ) {

echo <<<HTML
    <script>
                alert('minus ');
        </script>
HTML;

        $error = "";

        $row = $db->super_query("SELECT subscriptions FROM " . PREFIX . "_mywatch WHERE user_id={$member_id['user_id']}" );
        $list = explode(",", $row['subscriptions']);

        foreach ( $list as $daten ) {
                if( $daten == $id ) $achecker = "stop";
        }

        if( $achecker == "stop" ){
                $list = array_merge(array_diff($list, array($id)));
                $subsc = $db->safesql(implode( ",", $list ));
                //$subsc = implode( ",", $list );
                $db->query( "UPDATE " . PREFIX . "_mywatch set subscriptions='$subsc' where user_id = '{$member_id['user_id']}'" );
        }
                $buffer = "<a onclick=\"doMywatch('" . $id . "', 'plus'); \" title=\"" . $lang['news_minfav'] . "\">Подписатся</a>";
} else
        die( "error" );

$db->close();

@header( "Content-type: text/html; charset=" . $config['charset'] );
echo $buffer;
```

Comment: Can you format your code with line breaks and whitespace? Code that's actually readable makes people more willing to spend time on your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm right, the first time you click susbcribe, you will go in the `elseif( $_GET['action'] == "plus" )`, then your output will be `<a onclick=......>Unsubscibe</a>` and will be put inside your previous `<a id="subscript-id-3385">...</a>` so you will have both click events for subscribe and unsubscribe in the same element, so this can lead to some strange behaviour. I suggest you to wrap your link in a div and update that div only.

Comment: no, i'll go to plus. than `$buffer` would be `                    $buffer = "<a onclick=\"doMywatch('" . $id . "', 'minus'); \" title=\"" . $lang['news_minfav'] . "\">unsubscribe</a>";
`

Comment: My bad you are right, but both part of your code is doing similar process, the main problem is that you will have `<a id="subscript-id-3385" onclick="doMywatch('3385', 'plus'); return false;" ><a onclick="doMywatch('3385', 'minus');" title="...">unsubscribe</a></a>`